# how to secure Chrome Extension from Altering , spoofing and hacking

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I know this question was asked many times before but **everything changes every few months in terms of security measures and hacking methods**. ( *the most recent post i found was 2014 - 5 years ago.*  )

I'm trying to build an **extension** that checks if user/student is on the right page doing what he is suppose to do or not.

so if he was watching one of the **recommended tutorial** or **reading certain page** the extension should report that to the server but I don't know how to secure the extension from **hacking/modifying** by taking advantage of the most recent chrome security counter measures .

- Is there's a way to make sure that extension files are not altered using the front or back end ? ( *back end must be involved* )
- Is there is a way to keep the extension files in a 'bubble' not effected by any other scripts ? ( read only ).
- is there's a way to run a certain function from the backend to check and verify if certain file is not altered or maybe to scan the session?

  - **front end** : Javascript.
  - **Back end** : Python-flask.

Comment: Extension files are not affected by other scripts in the browser and never were. But a user can edit the files or spoof anything the extension sends and there's absolutely no way to prevent that. The more advanced users can even use a MitM proxy tool like Fiddler to modify the response body.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Doing so would be equivalent to effective DRM. No matter what you try to scan about the extension, the client could lie to you and just say what you want to hear.